# Bash: How to separate array elements with tabs - and print on the same line?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I have an array in bash...say, my_array:

```
my_array={1,2,3,4}
```

I need two requirements for this:
1) Print all of these elements on the same line, and 2) Separate each element with a tab.

When I print the elements out, here is what the output should be:

```
1    2    3    4
```

With each "gap" in between the elements being a tab.

Any suggestions on how to do this would be appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT**
Here's what I've tried so far:

1) I know I can print out an array on the same line as so:

```
echo {my_array[*]}
```

2) To get the desired tabs, I've tried making a variable with just a tab inside, and adding it to my array between each element:

```
temp="    "

for(...)
do
    ((my_array+=$i))
    ((my_array+=$temp))
done
```

This, however, gives me an error.

**EDIT 2**
Solution provided by Inan

This works:

```
printf '%s\t' "${my_array[@]}"
```

However, a couple things here; how would I delete the last tab, after the very last element?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'll put it in the EDIT - sorry, I completely forgot about this part.

Comment: @DarrelGulseth: did you mean to add `\t` between the elements in the array or when printing it?

Comment: @Inian, the solution you provided did work. However, I still have two more concerns: how would I get rid of the last tab (I don't want the tab after the last element). I also want a new line after the array has finished printing.

Comment: @DarrelGulseth: Use the most voted answer in the linked duplicate. Do `join_by() { local IFS="$1"; shift; echo "$*"; }` and define an array as `arr=(1 2 3 4)` and call the function as `join_by $'\t' "${arr[@]}"`

Comment: That's not a `bash` array; it's a regular string with the literal value `{1,2,3,4}`. `my_array=(1 2 3 4)` (or `my_array=({1,2,3,4})` if you really want to use the unnecessary brace expansion here) creates an array.

Comment: Thanks guys! I retried Mihai's answer and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Why not using "tr"?

```
my_array={1,2,3,4}
echo $my_array | tr "," "\t"
```

Result:

```
{1      2       3       4}
```

If:

```
my_array=(1,2,3,4)
echo $my_array | tr "," "\t"
```

Result:

```
1       2       3       4
```

Comment: Hmmm... didn't work for me. The first element prints, and the rest don't print at all.

Comment: Anybody else have ideas?